# How to access component parent element styles through template rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm making a card game and I need to know the width of the parent element (the player's hand) to calculate the margin for the cards.

i tried to get the styles just from the template element via this.$el but at the time of rendering the element is not created yet.  I tried to get the parent of the component via $refs but it is not created yet either,I thought I could get the styles by creating an element with the needed id and extracting the styles from it and delete it, but that didn't work either.

[The arrangment of the cards in the hand should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79SbH.png)

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="hand" ref="hand">
    <Hand :hand="hand" :card_width="150"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hand from "./components/Hand.vue";

export default {
  data () {
    return {
            message: 'ONE GAME!',
            colors: ["#C90000", "#379711", "#0956BF", "#FFC700"],
            cards: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'reverse', 'skip', 'draw2', 'wild', 'wild4'],
            top_card: {card: 1, color: 1},
            hand: []
        }
  },
  components: {
        'Hand': Hand
  },
  created: function() {
        this.hand = [
            {card:1, color: this.colors[1]},
            {card:1, color: this.colors[2]},
            {card:1, color: this.colors[3]},
        ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Hand.vue

```
<script>
    import Card from "./Card.vue";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {}
        },
        props: {
            hand: Array,
            card_width: Number,
        },
        components: {
            Card,
        },
        methods: {
            calculateMarginLeft(index, cards_count) {
                return parseInt(getComputedStyle(this.$refs.hand).width) - this.card_width / (cards_count - 1) * index + 'px';
            },
        },
    };

</script>

<template>
    <div class="hand" ref="hand">
        <Card :style="{'position':'absolute', 'z-index':index, 'margin-left': calculateMarginLeft()}" v-for="(card, index) in hand" :card="card.card" :color="card.color" :key="index" :width="this.card_width"  />
    </div>
</template>

<style>
#hand {
  width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

Card.vue

```
<template>
    <div v-html="this.cardsSvg[this.card]" class="card"></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['card','color', 'width'],
        data () {
            return {
                'cardsSvg': [some svg images for cards]
            }
        },

    }
</script>

<style>
    .card {
    fill: v-bind(color);
    width: v-bind(width) + 'px';
    height: 1.495 * v-bind(width) + 'px';
    }
</style>
```

Comment: use CSS only?..

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev if possible, yes

Comment: you need to provide your components' code. otherwise it's impossible to figure out what you want exactly in terms of actual code

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev added some code, by the way passing the card_width prop also applies to this problem, because i need to know the actual width of the card to calculate the margin. Maybe there is some obvious solution to make such an arrangement of cards in the hand throught several parametrs in css, but i dont know about it.

Comment: the problem is that the calculateMarginLeft function doesn`t work